# RecyclerView for chat app has display issue using Friebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Left is Mary and right is Bill , the speaker's textView will show on the right side , the situation is that Mary says 1 and 2 , it looks fine , just like the photo:
[image]

next step : the right side device is Bill who says a and b , it looks fine that is just what i want.
[image]

when they type words more and more , my issue is happen like this:
[image]

But when i leave the ChatGroup1 and enter it again , it looks fine
[image]

So my issue is that it has something wrong with realtime on display recyclerView

How can i fix this issue , i try to add `listData.clear();` , it's not working

Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance .

It's my chat channel layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_send" />


    <EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Type your message..."
        android:background="@drawable/edit_corner"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

it's my chat class for Firebase and recyclerView:

```
//global variable
private RecyclerView recyclerChat;
private ArrayList<ChatItem> listData = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerChatItemAdapter adapter;
private DatabaseReference root;
```

About FirebaseDatabase:

```
root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);
//send message to FirebaseDatabase
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                root.updateChildren(map);

                DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
                map2.put("name", user_name);
                map2.put("msg", editText2.getText().toString());

                message_root.updateChildren(map2);
                manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() , InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);//just hide the keyboard when send message
                editText2.setText("");
            }
        });
```

I think that may be my issue is just right here , about my recyclerView:

```
root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                ChatItem chatItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatItem.class);//put the data to my javabean from Firebase

                Log.d("Contacts:   ", chatItem.toString());

                listData.add(chatItem);
                recyclerChat.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);//just let the latest data below
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //append_right_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);

            }


            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        //        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerChat.setLayoutManager(manager);

        adapter = new RecyclerChatItemAdapter(this, listData);
        recyclerChat.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//when i leave the chat group and enter again , it looks fine because this.
```

It's my recyclerView adapter:

```
public class RecyclerChatItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerChatItemAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<ChatItem> mDatas;

    public RecyclerChatItemAdapter(Context context, List<ChatItem> mDatas) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDatas = mDatas;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=View.inflate(parent.getContext(),R.layout.for_chat_item_layout,null);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String myName=mDatas.get(position).getName();
        Contacts contacts=Contacts.getContacts();
        String createName=contacts.getName();
        if (myName.equals(createName)){
            holder.textRight.setText(mDatas.get(position).getMsg()+"("+mDatas.get(position).getName()+")");
            holder.textRight.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.textRight.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat_green));

        }else {
            holder.textLeft.setText(mDatas.get(position).getMsg()+"("+mDatas.get(position).getName()+")");
            holder.textLeft.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            holder.textLeft.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat_blue));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDatas.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView textLeft,textRight;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textLeft=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textLeft);
            textRight=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textRight);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have shown Adapter layout and adapter code... It can be visibility problem of view.

You may be set visibility for view.. So for that please ensure that you have written something like this..

```
    if (myName.equals(createName)){
                holder.textRight.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                holder.textLeft.setVisibility(GONE);
                holder.textRight.setText(mDatas.get(position).getMsg()+"("+mDatas.get(position).getName()+")");
                holder.textRight.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                holder.textRight.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat_green));

            }else {
                holder.textRight.setVisibility(GONE);
                holder.textLeft.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                holder.textLeft.setText(mDatas.get(position).getMsg()+"("+mDatas.get(position).getName()+")");
                holder.textLeft.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                holder.textLeft.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat_blue));

            }
```

Comment: thanks for your responding , i update the code for rcyclerView adapter , according to Visible , it looks that i don't use it , how should i fix my issue , thanks in advance.

Comment: checkout my answer again

Comment: thanks @Lalit Jadav , you solve my issue , it really a great help , god bless you